# What if a load balancer's idle timeout longer than the website settings

Tags: amazon-elb

Question as title. When the LB to webserver's connection is closed, however, the client and the LB's connection is active, Would the LB re-forward the request to the server? We had a double postback issue. Just guessing this could be the cause of it. Anyone has similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

We had sporadic 502 errors from a loadbalancer, and I found this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-alb-troubleshoot-502-errors/ which explains that the load balancer idle timeout should be shorter than the target http server keep alive timeout.

> The load balancer receives a request and forwards it to the target.
> The target receives the request and starts to process it, but closes
> the connection to the load balancer too early. This usually occurs
> when the duration of the keep-alive timeout for the target is shorter
> than the idle timeout value of the load balancer. Make sure that the
> duration of the keep-alive timeout is greater than the idle timeout
> value.